# Spring Boot, Spring Data & MongoDB Long Sequence not getting generated

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Spring Boot Version: 1.5.7.RELEASE
Spring Data
MongoDB

My attempt is to add a simple TODO in TODO Document in MongoDB. I was able to add it if I go by String id.But I want my id to be Long. And my requirement is to generate my own sequence. I am having issues generating sequence with the following code. Appreciate if you point where I am going wrong. I was able to add if I create my own id instead of using a sequence.

```
package com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

import com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.domain.ToDo;
import com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.domain.ToDoSequence;
import com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.repository.ToDoRepository;
import com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.repository.ToDoSequenceRepository;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey" })
public class SpringJerseyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private ToDoRepository todoRepository;

/**
 * The repository for the sequence {@link ToDoSequence}
 */
@Autowired
private ToDoSequenceRepository sequenceRepo;

// The sequence key name for the books
    private static final String ToDo_SEQ_KEY = ToDo.COLLECTION_NAME;

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(SpringJerseyApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringJerseyApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

    todoRepository.deleteAll();



    bootStrapToDo();

}



private void bootStrapToDo() throws Exception{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    Long sequenceId = sequenceRepo.getNextSequenceId(ToDo_SEQ_KEY);
    System.out.println(" Sequence ID is " + sequenceId);
    ToDo td1 = new ToDo(sequenceId,"Work on Java", "Learn Lambdas, Modules & clojures", dateFormat.format(date));
    todoRepository.save(td1);

    //ToDo td2 = new ToDo(sequenceRepo.getNextSequenceId(ToDo_SEQ_KEY),"Work on Swift", "Learn Optionals", dateFormat.format(date));
    //todoRepository.save(td2);

}
```

}

ToDo Domain

```
 package com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.domain;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = ToDo.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class ToDo {

public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "todos";


@Id
private Long id;

private String summary;
private String description;
private String dateCreated;

public ToDo() {
}

public ToDo(Long todoID, String summary, String description, String dateCreated) {
    this.id = todoID;
    this.summary = summary;
    this.description = description;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}




public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long todoID) {
    this.id = todoID;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("ToDo[id=%s, summary='%s', description='%s' , dateCreated='%s']", id, summary, description,
            dateCreated);
}

}
```

Custom Sequence Domain

ToDoSequence

```
package com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.domain;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = ToDoSequence.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class ToDoSequence {
 public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "todoSequence";

@Id
private String id;
private Long sequence;



public ToDoSequence() {

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}

public void setSequence(Long seq) {
    this.sequence = seq;
}

}
```

ToDoRepository

```
package com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.domain.ToDo;

public interface ToDoRepository extends MongoRepository<ToDo, Long> {

public ToDo findBySummary(String summary);

public List<ToDo> findByDateCreated(String dateCreated);
```

}

ToDoSequenceRepository

```
package com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.repository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.FindAndModifyOptions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.srisris.tapasya.springjersey.domain.ToDoSequence;

@Repository
public class ToDoSequenceRepository {

@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperation;

public Long getNextSequenceId(String key) throws Exception {
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(key));

    // increase sequence id by 1
    Update update = new Update();
    update.inc("sequence", 1);

    // return new increased id
    FindAndModifyOptions options = new FindAndModifyOptions();
    options.returnNew(true);

    // this is the magic happened.
    ToDoSequence seqId = mongoOperation.findAndModify(query, update, options, ToDoSequence.class);

    // if no id, throws SequenceException
    // optional, just a way to tell user when the sequence id is failed to
    // generate.
    if (seqId == null) {
        throw new Exception(seqId + " Unable to get sequence id for key : " + key);
    }
    return seqId.getSequence();

}

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring-cloud, why did you change it back. There is zero mention of spring cloud code, only spring data.

Comment: Apart from your comment, can you point out what is wrong with the code? Why I am unable to generate a sequence?

Comment: What isn't working?  Is the number always zero?  Is there an exception?  More information please.

Comment: I get the seqId as null and hence throws the following exception              
    if (seqId == null) {
        throw new Exception(seqId + " Unable to get sequence id for key : " + key);
    }

Comment: Auto Sequencing is not working with the above approach. I still fail to understand why